# What can a specter without Life Drain do?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack

I'll be running M.T. Black's [*Tower of the Mad Mage*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/180106/Tower-of-the-Mad-Mage--Adventure) adventure in D&D 5e next week.

On p. 8, there is a [specter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/specter) that, according to the description, has been weakened to where it can't use its Life Drain ability:

> *Note.* The specter has been weakened by the close proximity of the chantry. Therefore, it cannot use its *life drain* ability.

Since that seems to be all a specter can attack with, what can this specter use as its attack?

Comment: Related (monsters with no options): "[What damaging options does a lich have while in an anti-magic field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157123)", "[Can a monster with no melee attack make an Opportunity Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100702)"

Comment: Odd that they refer to it as an ability since Life Drain is listed as an action in the stat block. It makes me wonder if they mean the max HP drain side effect rather than the attack itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The only things it could effectively use are magic items

You are correct that *Life Drain* is the only option in the [Specter's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/specter) statblock but it still has all the options that every creature has, including (but not limited to): unarmed strikes, improvised weapons, magic items, and grapple/shove.

Unfortunately the Specter has a -5 Strength modifier so it will almost never grapple anybody, and its unarmed strikes and improvised weapon attacks will always deal 0 damage. *Tower of the Mad Mage* doesn't mention the Specter as having access to any magic items so those are out of the question which means we've exhausted all of our options...

Comment: Minor nitpick, but the throwing weapon only works if your DM rules that the thing it is throwing is a finesse weapon, else it'll be doing 1d4-5 damage. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108337/does-the-thrown-property-mean-i-can-attack-with-my-dex

Comment: @Theik Wow I never realized you always add Strength to improvised weapons. I guess the specter has no options then

Comment: I'm thinking of maybe using the Poltergeist variant.